Efficiently query django Query
We are working on newspaper with django. Before read further Let me show you the code.
    # Fetch lead, top, and other filtered news
    news_objects = news.objects.filter(website=host, is_published__in=[True], published_date__lt=current_datetime).only('Category','title','news_brief','image','img_caption','published_date','news_id')
    lead = news_objects.filter(status='lead').order_by('-published_date').first()
    top = news_objects.filter(status='top').order_by('-published_date')[:4]
    filtered_news = news_objects.exclude(status__in=['lead', 'top']).order_by('-published_date')

    # Fetch filtered categories and prefetch limited news related to filtered categories
    categories_with_news = category.objects.filter(website=host, show_front__in=[True]).prefetch_related(
        Prefetch('category', queryset=filtered_news, to_attr='limited_news')
    )

    # Limit the news to the first 5 for each category
    for category in categories_with_news:
        category.limited_news = category.limited_news[:6]`

Below code will fetch all news in specific domain. News contains more then 10k
news_objects = news.objects.filter(website=host, is_published__in=[True], published_date__lt=current_datetime).only('Category','title','news_brief','image','img_caption','published_date','news_id')

Below code will get only 5 news from news_objects

lead = news_objects.filter(status='lead').order_by('-published_date').first()
top = news_objects.filter(status='top').order_by('-published_date')[:4]

below code will get all the category which will display in front along with their data.
categories_with_news = category.objects.filter(website=host, show_front__in=[True]).prefetch_related(
        Prefetch('category', queryset=filtered_news, to_attr='limited_news')
    )

Again below code will fetch 6 news per category.
for category in categories_with_news:
        category.limited_news = category.limited_news[:6]

Here my problem is I don't think so this is good idea to fetch all the news for cause I will need not more then 60 news. How to do it efficiently.
I tried limiting the query to 300 but there also a problem may be in some category no 6 may be in 350 position.

Have you measured whether you have a performance issue, or is this theoretical?

It's performance issue. Response time is degrading over time. 1 month ago response time was 300ms avg. now it's 650ms+

Alright. Have you used profilers such as Django Debug Toolbar to see what the queries look like? Do you have indexes on the columns you're sorting and filtering on?

I didn't use Django Debug Toolbar. I do have indexes.

Well, you should use a profiler first, so you know what the bottleneck is. Did you verify that the indexes are being used? (Django Debug Toolbar will tell you that too.)

Can you also add the raw query that ORM generated?

A few things:

don't iterate over categies_with_news, adjust your limit when you actually have to (such as serialization/response time).
don't use __in=[True] just =True instead.
make sure you index status published_date website
Make sure your responses are pagignated.

#1 is your biggest killer.
for this kind of query with <10million records your response times should be around .2 +-.1s or so.

How often do new news items arrive? I'm assuming that retrieving news is a far more frequent operation than adding new news. So add a bit more work to the less frequent operation. Basically, keep some extra information which changes fairly infrequently in the DB, to speed up retrieval queries.
You could maintain a top_six flag on your news objects. Every time a new news item is added, retrieve the current top six in the new_new's category, un-set the flag for the one which is no longer in the top six because of the new addition, and add the new one with that flag set. You probably  also need to run an hourly? daily? operation to take all the top_six items and clear the flag on any which are too old? ( or maybe unpopular?) to retain the status.
Retrieving the current top six for some or all categories will filter on this flag. You then won't need to iterate over categories with news or slice for retrieval. You'll never retrieve more than six in any category but a single DB query can fetch news across all or multiple (__in) categories.
